# UpdateParameters with datetime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to use the sqldatasource.UpdateParameters.Add() to add a date/time to my database table.
The column data type is smalldatetime and it is displaying in a gridview just fine. If I try end edit this date/time, then save the changes the other fields update, but the date/time remains the same. I have tried using the DateTime.Parse methods with no success.

```
sqlds1.UpdateParameters.Add("MeasurementDateTime", Data.DbType.DateTime, currentMsrmntDateTime.Text)
```

I use the above code for each respective value and parameter pair, but the date/time field doesn't update. The update statement again works for all parameters except the date/time.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateCathodeTemps]
(
    @MeasurementTypeCode int
    ,@MeasurementDateTime smalldatetime
    ,@Value nvarchar(50)
    ,@Comments nvarchar(512)
    ,@IsMeasurementChecked bit
    ,@MeasurementCheckedBy nvarchar(50)
    ,@BakeDetailsID int
    -- 7 Params
) AS



BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE tblMeasurementsAtPeriod
SET MeasurementDateTime =  @MeasurementDateTime, 
Value = @Value, 
Comments = @Comments, 
MeasurementCheckedBy = @MeasurementCheckedBy, 
IsMeasurementChecked = @IsMeasurementChecked, 
MeasurementTypeCode = @MeasurementTypeCode, 
BakeDetailsID = @BakeDetailsID  
WHERE MeasurementDateTime = @MeasurementDateTime AND MeasurementTypeCode = @MeasurementTypeCode


IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END



COMMIT
```

No errors are thrown when I hit the save button, all the other fields are updated, but the date/time remains the same. I have checked the values as they are being passed to the stored procedure, and they are as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem in the `WHERE` clause of your stored procedure:

```
WHERE MeasurementDateTime = @MeasurementDateTime AND 
      MeasurementTypeCode = @MeasurementTypeCode
```

So you are updating to the exact same date!

The where clause picks those rows with a given `MeasurementDateTime`, you then update those rows but the `MeasurementDateTime` that you are updating to is the same (obviously).

Perhaps you want 2 params:

```
,@OriginalMeasurementDateTime smalldatetime
,@NewMeasurementDateTime smalldatetime
```

Comment: I don't follow, can you explain.

Comment: How can I do this in my code behind short of adding another text box with the old value and the new value to change to?

Comment: That would appear to be a slightly different question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your UPDATE query may be flawed -

You are trying to *update* `MeasurementDateTime`, but your WHERE clause is looking for records with the same value that you are trying to update `MeasurementDateTime` to, so you won't be updating the same records.  You'll either update no records (if no records have that same value), or you'll be updating OTHER records.

That may be what you're trying to do, but it seems odd to me.  It seems more logical to have another parameter for the *previous* value to search for and update them to the *new* value:

```
UPDATE tblMeasurementsAtPeriod
SET MeasurementDateTime =  @NewMeasurementDateTime, /* NEW date value */
    Value = @Value, 
    Comments = @Comments, 
    MeasurementCheckedBy = @MeasurementCheckedBy, 
    IsMeasurementChecked = @IsMeasurementChecked, 
    MeasurementTypeCode = @MeasurementTypeCode, 
    BakeDetailsID = @BakeDetailsID  
    WHERE MeasurementDateTime = @OldMeasurementDateTime /* OLD date value */
      AND MeasurementTypeCode = @MeasurementTypeCode
```